# Difference between "not equal" operators <> and != in PHP

Tags: php, operators

In PHP, is there any difference between the `!=` and `<>` operators?

In the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), it states:

```
$a != $b    Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
$a <> $b    Not equal   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b after type juggling.
```

I guess there are no huge differences but I'm curious.

Comment: Well there is the fact that most people dont use `<>` as an op for non-equality in php even though its allowed :-)

Comment: `!=` is probably more common...

Comment: @prodigitalson that may actually be and argument :) (readability etc)

Comment: @everybody, any difference in speed? (though probably no significant at all)

Comment: @Trufa: Indeed... even moreso IMO because as Alex pointed out there is also the strict comparison which is often used... it doesnt make much sense to do `<>` for loose and then still have to do `!==` for strict.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the non-equality checking operators <> and !=?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671785/what-is-the-difference-between-the-non-equality-checking-operators-and)

Comment: `<>` may be convenient for VBA, Pascal or Excel programmers

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the main Zend implementation there is not any difference.  You can get it from the [Flex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_lexical_analyser) description of the PHP language [scanner](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_scanner.l):

```
<ST_IN_SCRIPTING>"!="|"<>" {
    return T_IS_NOT_EQUAL;
}
```

Where `T_IS_NOT_EQUAL` is the generated token. So the [Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) [parser](http://svn.php.net/repository/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) does not distinguish between `<>` and `!=` tokens and treats them equally:

```
%nonassoc T_IS_EQUAL T_IS_NOT_EQUAL T_IS_IDENTICAL T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL
%nonassoc '<' T_IS_SMALLER_OR_EQUAL '>' T_IS_GREATER_OR_EQUAL
```

Answer (score 8):

They are the same. However there are also `!==` and `===` operators which test for exact equality, defined by value *and* type.

Answer (score 7):

`<>` means either bigger or smaller. `!=` means not equal. They basically mean the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

As everyone is saying they are identical, one from one language branch C-style/shell, one from some others including MySQL which was highly integrated in the past.

`<>` should be considered syntactic sugar, a synonym for `!=` which is the proper PHP style for not-equal.

Further emphasised by the triple character identity function `!==`.

Answer (score 3):

The operators `<>` and `!=` are the same.

However, as a matter of style, I prefer to use `<>` when dealing with **numerical variables**.

That is, if:

- `$a` is an integer
- `$b` is an integer

instead of asking:

```
// if $a is not equal to $b
if ($a != $b)
```

I will ask:

```
// if $a is either less than or greater than $b
if ($a <> $b)
```

This is a visual hint / reminder in my code that `$a` and `$b` are *definitely* both intended to be **numerical** rather than one or both being intentionally `strings`.